# Use spawn() to spawn child process but still blocks the current caller function

Tags: node.js, subprocess, ipc

I have a function that spawns s child process asynchronously, so that I can listen on errors from child process, like this:

```js
function runCmd(cmd, args, cwd) {
        let childProc = childProcess.spawn(cmd, args, {
            encoding: 'utf8',
            cwd: cwd,
            stdio: ['ignore', 'pipe', 'pipe']
        });
        childProc.on('error', (err) => {
            console.error(`backend error: ${err}`);
        })
        childProc.stdout.on('data', (data) => {
            console.log(`stdout: ${data}`);
        });
          
        childProc.stderr.on('data', (data) => {
            console.error(`stderr: ${data}`);
        });
          
        childProc.on('close', (code) => {
            console.log(`child process closed with code ${code}`);
        });

        childProc.on('exit', () => {
            console.log(`child process is gone`);
        });
}
```

### Observation vs. Expectation

However, this function exits immediately, while I want it to block until I find a way to quit in one of the event listeners.

I've tried variousl ways such as using while(true)-loop (it blocks everything including the child process because nodeJS is single threaded), or a promise such as

```js
await new Promise( (resolve) => {
    child.on('close', resolve)
})
```

### Workarounds

I could've used `spawnSync` but it hangs if child process crashes, without catching any errors along the way.

The funny thing is that if I put the `spawnSync` into a try-catch block, I still don't get anything in the catch block, meaning the `spawnSync()` call simply hangs.

I've been comfortable with Python's subprocess module, where the parent process always gets info back when a synchronously spawned child process crashes.

So NodeJS's way of handling this, i.e., simply hangs forever, is a bit odd to me.

### Questions

How could I get the best of both worlds of `spawn` and `spawnSync`? i.e.,

- Block the function until the child process finishes or crashes
- Get all the stdout/stderr info from child process no matter what

Comment: As you said, `spawn` is asynchronous, the function `runCmd` returns without waiting your child process exits, so it always exits immediately. And if you use `spawnSync `, you need to put `spawnSync ` into a `try-catch` block, then you can catch the errors.

Comment: @lx1412 The funny thing is that it actually never reaches my catch block. It simply hangs at spawnSync.

Comment: This isn't going to work the way you want and trying to force this into your pre-existing mental model isn't going to end well. Blocking the main thread on a child process is not usually a good idea in any language. The closest that you can come is to have your function return a promise that resolves in your child's exit handler. You can `await` that in the caller.